# Multiple modules List in a Dashboard - Yeoman MEANJS Generator

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, meanjs, mean.io

I am new in MEANJS and someone suggest me to go with MEANJS for kickstart app. I have started working on it and trying to make an architecture for my app but i am confused in 1 thing that what will be the architecture if i need to work in cross modules.

What I want is that I have 2 CRUD modules Articles and Needs now I want to show my Needs list and Articles list on my dashboard (core module home page). Please help me and how can i communicate between different modules. App is medium size.

Waiting for suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

I think your best way of doing this is by using the REST api's of each module. In `core/client/services` add new services for retrieving the data from `/api/articles` and `/api/needs` (use the same services as in `articles/client/services/articles.client.service.js`).

Call the services in `core/client/controllers/home.client.controller.js` to get the data and display it in `core/client/views/home.client.view.html`.

Hope this helps a bit. Im also quite new to MeanJS.